# Blogger Recent Posts Console Error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, blogger

I found this recent Blogger script that will show recent posts of a certain label or tag. The script works fine. However, if I use this script more than once, to show recent posts of a different label, and throws an error of:

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Looking at the script, I cannot figure out what is causing this, or how to fix it.

```
<script style='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    function labelthumbs(json) {
        document.write('<ul class="label_with_thumbs">');
        for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
            var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
            var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
            var posturl;
            if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
            for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
                if (entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && entry.link[k].type == 'text/html') {
                    var commenttext = entry.link[k].title;
                    var commenturl = entry.link[k].href;
                }
                if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                    posturl = entry.link[k].href;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var thumburl;
            try {
                thumburl = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
            } catch (error) {
                s = entry.content.$t;
                a = s.indexOf("<img");
                b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
                c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
                d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
                if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
                    thumburl = d;
                } else thumburl = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-O-vjxP03hYo/UXVtH90_iQI/AAAAAAAAAG4/60hz9Rn5FWA/s1600/No+Image+1.gif';
            }
            var postdate = entry.published.$t;
            var cdyear = postdate.substring(0, 4);
            var cdmonth = postdate.substring(5, 7);
            var cdday = postdate.substring(8, 10);
            var monthnames = new Array();
            monthnames[1] = "Jan";
            monthnames[2] = "Feb";
            monthnames[3] = "Mar";
            monthnames[4] = "Apr";
            monthnames[5] = "May";
            monthnames[6] = "June";
            monthnames[7] = "July";
            monthnames[8] = "Aug";
            monthnames[9] = "Sept";
            monthnames[10] = "Oct";
            monthnames[11] = "Nov";
            monthnames[12] = "Dec";
            document.write('<li class="clearfix">');
            if (showpostthumbnails == true) document.write('<a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top"><img class="label_thumb" src="' + thumburl + '"/></a>');
            document.write('<strong><a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top">' + posttitle + '</a></strong><br>');
            if ("content" in entry) {
                var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
            } else if ("summary" in entry) {
                var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;
            } else var postcontent = "";
            var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
            postcontent = postcontent.replace(re, "");
            if (showpostsummary == true) {
                if (postcontent.length < numchars) {
                    document.write('');
                    document.write(postcontent);
                    document.write('');
                } else {
                    document.write('');
                    postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, numchars);
                    var quoteEnd = postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");
                    postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, quoteEnd);
                    document.write(postcontent + '...');
                    document.write('');
                }
            }
            var towrite = '';
            var flag = 0;
            document.write('<br>');
            if (showpostdate == true) {
                towrite = towrite + monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth, 10)] + '-' + cdday + ' - ' + cdyear;
                flag = 1;
            }
            if (showcommentnum == true) {
                if (flag == 1) {
                    towrite = towrite + ' | ';
                }
                if (commenttext == '1 Comments') commenttext = '1 Comment';
                if (commenttext == '0 Comments') commenttext = 'No Comments';
                commenttext = '<a href="' + commenturl + '" target ="_top">' + commenttext + '</a>';
                towrite = towrite + commenttext;
                flag = 1;;
            }
            if (displaymore == true) {
                if (flag == 1) towrite = towrite + ' | ';
                towrite = towrite + '<a href="' + posturl + '" class="url" target ="_top">More Â»</a>';
                flag = 1;;
            }
            document.write(towrite);
            document.write('</li>');
            if (displayseparator == true) if (i != (numposts - 1)) document.write('');
        }
        document.write('</ul>');
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var numposts = 3;
    var showpostthumbnails = true;
    var displaymore = false;
    var displayseparator = true;
    var showcommentnum = false;
    var showpostdate = false;
    var showpostsummary = true;
    var numchars = 100;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/video?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=labelthumbs"></script>
```

There are a variety of these scripts available, some similar and some not. However, it appears as though they ALL throw this error. Is it possible the error is caused by the feed itself, or is it the script?

Specifically though, the console says the error is with this variable:

```
var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
```

Comment: It is obvious that json.feed.entry[i] do not contain any value. Hence entry variable remains undefined. You need to debug more!

Comment: I disagree. The error only happens when the script is used more than once. If it didn't contain any value, why is it that it works when used once?

Comment: There are too many unknowns here for us to be sure what is wrong. For example we don't know what `numposts` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being caused by the `numposts` variable value being more than the number of posts present in the specific label

For example , your label might be containing only a single post but if you supplied the `numposts`'s value to be more than 1 , then on the second iteration of the for loop , it will throw the above error as their won't be any post to iterate over

For working demo , check http://jsbin.com/quniyifuna/1/ , here two instances of the above code are working fine without any errors in the console

In the second demo , http://jsbin.com/dosuhi/1/ , I have given `numposts` a value greater than the posts present in that specific label , therefore in the console you would find the same error as yours

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't change the label name because blogger displays related posts under a specific label only for 1 time. However, you must try to change the blogger label from last line on your JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/video?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=labelthumbs"></script>
```

Just change the **video** label to another one, I'm sure, it'll works...

Comment: Nah, the first label is video, the second is photo.